# Mathjax error when displaying formulas

Tags: javascript, php, mathjax

When I try to display Mathjax formulas, sometimes this weird bug appears.

[bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZI3k.png)

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Here is the way how I implemented Mathjax:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> 
 MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}}); </script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"> </script>
```

With best greetings,
Leon

Comment: You need to include the script **BEFORE** you do any code with it.

Comment: The configuration is fine and belongs before the call to MathJax. But please add a minimal live sample that exhibits the problem. There's little to tell from a screenshot.

Comment: It is included in the head, the code is run in the body.

Comment: And here is one example: http://www.mathespass.at/testversion/klasse4/kreis_umfang2.php, but the bug just happens sometimes; please remove the 2 from the URL.

Comment: Post the latex please. Is it only happening for inline mathjax lines?